# Cannot drop database in postgres

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I would like to unserstand why I am not able to drop a database from cmd:
I execute the command: `drop database if exists <db_name>` but the result is as below:

```
postgres=# drop database testV5;

ERROR:  database "testV5" does not exist
```

knowing that the database exists:

```
postgres=# \l
                                  Liste des bases de donnÚes


   Nom     | PropriÚtaire | Encodage |  Collationnement   |    Type caract.    |    Droits d'accÞs
  testV4   | postgres     | UTF8     | French_Canada.1252 | French_Canada.1252 |
  testV5   | postgres     | UTF8     | French_Canada.1252 | French_Canada.1252 |
  postgres | postgres     | UTF8     | French_Canada.1252 | French_Canada.1252 |
  template0| postgres     | UTF8     | French_Canada.1252 | French_Canada.1252 |          
  template1| postgres     | UTF8     | French_Canada.1252 | French_Canada.1252 |
```

Can anyone explain that please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sure that the error message actually is `database "testv5" does not exist`.

Answer (score 1):

You created the database with double quotes, so the name is [case sensitive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) now. You need to use the dreaded double quotes when dropping the database as well:

```
drop database "testV5";
```

---

Note that using quoted identifiers is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)